# transform every 3rd letter to uppercase

Tags: javascript

how to transform every 3rd character to uppercase. for example this string `pifedvcbtauzkwgnxyjrhmq` converted into piFedVcbTauKkwGnxYjrHmq.

here is what i've done so far

```
function up3rdletter(str){
        var i, result = '';
        for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            if(i > 0 && i % 3 == 0){
                result += str[i].toUpperCase();
            }else{
                result += str[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

the script above return `pifEdvCbtAuzKwgNxyJrhMq`, it start converting from 4th letter. if I change the modulo number to 2 it become `piFeDvCbTaUzKwGnXyJrHmQ`

Comment: `if (i % 3 === 2)`... (or `if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0)`), it's that easy. )

Comment: wow, briliant! please put this comment in answer so that i can accept it

Comment: Good opportunity to use the conditional operator: `result += (i + 1) % 3? str[i] : str[i].toUpperCase()`. ;-). Not all browsers support accessing string characters by index, *charAt* might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather trivial: indexing in JS starts from 0, but you want to change letters based on 1-based index, natural for human beings. ) Solution? Either shift the remainder check:

```
result += i % 3 === 2 ? str[i].toUpperCase() : str[i];
```

... or go on checking against 0, but advance `i` instead:

```
result += (i + 1) % 3 ? str[i] : str[i].toUpperCase();
```

But actually, I'd probably write it as follows:

```
result = str.replace(/(..)(.)/g, function(_, m1, m2) { 
  return m1 + m2.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: i know indexing in JS start from 0. i just confuse to use the right modulo return number, changed to what you suggested and it works good..awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
function up3rdletter(str){
        var i, result = '';
        var counter = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            if(i > 0 || counter % 3 == 0){
                result += str[i].toUpperCase();
            }else{
                result += str[i];
            }
        counter++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```